# Django ManytoMany not showing in admin

Tags: django, django-models

As my models are in ManyToMany relationship so connection should be in both ways, but are not.

For example in the admin for the `BusinessProfile` section I am able to see the name and image fields of `Services` model as they are in a ManyToMany relationship, but this not the case for the opposite. I am unable to see `BusinessProfile` models field in `Services` model in admin.

Is my model structure correct?

I have also attached images.[image: BusinessProfile view in admin]
[image: Services view in admin]

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image', blank = True)
    #business_profile = models.ManyToManyField("BusinessProfile", blank=True, related_name="business_of_services")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Service - {}".format(self.name)


class BusinessProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique =True)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    pan_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    pan_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    service  = models.ManyToManyField("Service", blank=True, related_name="services_of_business")
    image  = models.ManyToManyField("Service", related_name="image_of_business")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Business - {}".format(self.business_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use reversed many to many admin, you can use inlines. See [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

Example code in document.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Group.members.through

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('members',)
```